# How do I put a p and an a tag inline in html?

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I am trying to put a `<p>` tag inline with an `<a>` tag, but I can't figure out how. I've tried several display types in css, but they either don't work or do something weird to it.

(Here is a bunch of unnecessary words because the thing is saying there is too much code and not enough words. I think its pretty dumb because what I said is enough unless someone specifically asks for details about something).

Here's some example code:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #efefef;
}

header {
 margin: 0;
 margin-top: -10px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

header p {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "arial";
 font-size: 50px;
 color: #3c3c3c;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

header a {
}

#information {
 width: 500px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 7px 7px 4px grey;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-top: 150px;
}

#information p {
 font-family: "arial";
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #1febff;
}

#delete {
 margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>SaHa | Color Scheme</title>
 <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <p>SaHa</p>

  <a href="#">Menu</a>
 </header>

 <div id="information">
  <p>Pretend that there is a bunch of important information here even though there really isn't.
     This is normally where a message that actually means something would go, but this is just a
     placeholder because I have nothing important to put here right now.
  </p>
 </div>

 <div id="delete"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you specify which elements in your example code you want inline?

Generally using `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` will make elements flow as if they were text. They will sit next to each other and jump to new lines when their container width gets too narrow.  Browsers commonly apply `display: block` to `<p>` elements [by default.](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_p.asp)

Assuming we are talking about the contents of your `<header>`, I added the following rule to your existing CSS. Check it out [in action.](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/VMWqPj)

```
header p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on further comments, here is a solution to what you are looking for.

First of all I've wrapped your menu items in a `nav` element and made your main title a `h1` element. Search engines like this better. A `h1` element is also displayed inline by default and respects `text-align` properties on its parent container (which in this case is `header`).

```
<h1>SaHa</h1>
<nav>
  <a href="#">Menu</a>
  <a href="#">Thing</a>
  <a href="#">Stuff</a>
</nav>
```

On the CSS side I've made two crucial changes.

**First**, I've center-aligned your `header` text. This centers the new `h1` element. Additionally I've set `position: relative` because we will need it in the next step.

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

**Second**, to position your menu to the right side of the screen I've lifted it from the regular flow of content with `position: absolute`. Now, by specifying either a  `top` or `bottom` **and** `left` or `right`, we can position the menu anywhere in the header. Why the header? Because it is the nearest parent to `nav` that has a `relative` position. This is why we set it earlier!

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Try changing the values for `right` and `bottom` in [this Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/BwZvYr). Try changing `right` to `left` and see what happens. What happens if you remove `position: relative` from `.header`?

Comment: Thank you, that is almost what I wanted. But how do I put the SaHa logo back in the center and move the "menu" to the right?

Comment: Check out [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/Misacorp/pen/BwZvYr). If it's what you're looking for I'd be happy to update my answer and explain what I've done in more detail.

Comment: I'm still a little confused with how you positioned "SaHa" in the center, but the nav elements to the right.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain this. I hope it is easy to understand!

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with codepen, but could you send me a new link I don't think it's updated.

Comment: I am referring to my answer [just above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499647/3160385). An updated Codepen link is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Just to be clear, the Codepen code has not changed. What I have changed is my answer where I explain **how** I positioned "SaHa" in the center, but the nav elements to the right.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your HTML, try directly typing  or

   after whatever text you want it to appear.

For example:`<div>When i came<a> ut yiur name</a>so what do i do</div>`

2. In your CSS body, try inline-block or just inline parameters with DISPLAY property to get any image or text into the normal flow of a line.

For example:

a {display:inline-block;}